# Calculate how much a point is worth based on played games

Tags: math

My problem I have is that I need to calculate out how much a point is worth based on played games.

If a team plays a match it can get 3 points for a win, 1 point for a tie and 0 points for a loss.

And the problem here is following:

**Team 1** 
*Wins:8 Tie:2 Loss:3 Points:26 Played Games: 13*

**Team 2**
*Wins:8 Tie:3 Loss:4 Points:27 Played Games: 15*

And here you can see that **Team 2** has 1 more point than **Team 1** has. But **Team 2** has played 2 more matches and have a lesser win % then **Team 1** has. But if you should list these two then **Team 2** would get a higher "rating" then **Team 1** has.

So how should the math look for this to make it fair? where **Team 1** will have a better score here then **Team 2** ?

Comment: If the teams were told at the beginning of the season that this is how the points and ratings work then it would ***not be fair*** to change it now.  You set up a system where there is never a penalty for playing more games and always a possible gain.  Team 2 took advantage of that.  That's fair.

Comment: Well this system is not live at this moment, and just under construction. So I want to set up a fair system at the beginning for everyone

Comment: The math behind this isn't hard, if you want something like a "*Win%*" that would be `TotalScore/GamesPlayed`.  If you want say a "*Normalized Win-Score*" that would be `(TotalScore/GamesPlayed)*MaxGames` where `MaxGames` is the maximum possible number of games played for any team (appears to be 15 so far).

Comment: Yeh but the problem with that is there will be no limit of MaxGames here, one team can play 50 matches if they want to

Comment: But the problem with that is that it discourages any team with a perfect score (say 3-0) from playing anymore games.

Comment: Well both yes and no, becuase if you do like Andonaeus wrote here it should be then sum(points) / playedGames * sum(points)

so in my example then should Team 1 get 52 points and Team 2 46 points

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just divide by the number of games to get the average points per game played.

Team1: 2.0 ppg

Team2: 1.8 ppg

Comment: No, it should just be Sum(Points)/playedGames

Answer (score 0):

Okey first of all thanks for the help.
And the solution of this is the following:

p/pg * p = Real points

*p = Sum(points),
pg = Played games*

So for the example up top the real points will be:

**Team 1**: 52

**Team 2**: 48.6